# generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView and generics.ListCreateAPIView format dates differently

Tags: android, django, gson, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework APIViews to implement REST APIs around my models. One of the models is the following:

```
class HadithTag(models.Model):
  """A model describing a tag for hadiths."""
  name = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
  added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

It has the following serializer:

```
class HadithTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = HadithTag
    fields = ['name', 'added_on', 'updated_on']
```

And the following URL patterns:

```
url(r'^apis/hadithtags/$', apiviews.HadithTagSetView.as_view()),
url(r'^apis/hadithtags/(?P<pk>\w+)$', apiviews.HadithTagView.as_view()),
```

And the following API view classes:

```
class HadithTagSetView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = HadithTag.objects.all()
  serializer_class = HadithTagSerializer


class HadithTagView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  queryset = HadithTag.objects.all()
  serializer_class = HadithTagSerializer
```

Now my problem is that for some reason the format of the dates `added_on` and `updated_on` are returned differently when I run a GET request on `apis/hadithtags` vs when I create a new object with a POST request on `apis/hadithtags` and get the new object. The former returns the following format:

[{"name":"Test","added_on":"2015-07-04T21:57:25Z","updated_on":"2015-07-04T21:57:25Z"}]

While the latter returns:

{"name":"Test","added_on":"2015-07-04T21:57:25.288083Z","updated_on":"2015-07-04T21:57:25.288118Z"}

As you can see, doing a GET returns the datetime without milliseconds, while doing a POST returns the datetime with milliseconds included.

This is causing problems when I try to use Java's Gson library to parse the datetimes. It succeeds with the first one but fails with the second one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeing this issue because Django creates a date with microseconds when you do the post request. However, when you save to the database, the microseconds are truncated, so you get a different result when you do the get request later. Support was added for microseconds in DateTime fields in MySQL in [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#database-backends).

You can define the [`DateTimeField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) explicitly, and specify the date format you require. See [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for an explanation of date formats.

```
class HadithTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    added_on = DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    updated_on = DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    class Meta:
        model = HadithTag
        fields = ['name', 'added_on', 'updated_on']
```

Comment: Your theory makes perfect sense, because even when I specify 'iso-8601' as the format, I still get the same problem. However, when I explicitly specify the format without milliseconds like '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', the problem doesn't happen.